# Weird SSL issue opening a simple Text file, how is it possible?

Tags: html, ssl, firefox, ssl-certificate, cloudflare

I'm having a werid SSL "Mixed Content" warning on my test website, so to exclude everything I created a simple HTML page, and then also a TXT file. Even the TXT file show a security warning, the website is also under Cloudflare with Full setting and of course it has a certificate. seems that every file on this server have the same issue, I really have no idea what else to check.

**edit**: I turned on the debug mode to exclude cache issues as well, same error.

**edit 2**: only Firefox is showing this warning on the padlock.

**edit 3**: Firefox seems to not load any certificate.

**edit 4**: Also a picture gives the same certificate warning

Comment: Did you visit the page before you added the ssl cert? If so this is likely what it is, if you can show the cert chain from your inspector > security panel or provide the URL?

Comment: @rich I don't see a security panel in code inspector (firefox) the certificate was added before adding any page to the website. Both desktop Chrome and mobile doesn't show any yellow triangle or warning of sort. So far only replicated on desktop Firefox, already purged varnish and cloudflare cache other than switching to development mode.

Comment: Run the site through this, if there are problems it will tell you https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Comment: Additionally, the padlock sign in general these days is only shown if the site has issues with its certificate chain (or lack of).  To check on FF it should be under Options > Advanced > Encryption > View Certificates. I'm not at a computer right now so I'm not 100% but it is there somewhere.

Comment: @rich I ran differnet SSL tester, this one is no different, it returns that the SSL is correctly configured and secured by let's encrypy (that's cause I disable cloudflare while testing, otherwise would return cloudflare). However Firefox show no name for the certificate, it looks more like a Firefox bug or something.

Comment: @rich in certificates it is missing Let's Encrypt but on a sifferent website without cloudflare it is loading it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Ok thanks to server surpport we got to the bottom of this. In practice Firefox seems to have an "utility" to load the favicon for your website; unfortunately on the test site there were no favicon file to load; the file was missing and the 301 were redirecting over HTTP connection. So I set the favicon in the `head` section:

`<link rel="icon" href="favicon.png" sizes="32x32" />`

and this resolved the issue. the TXT and HTML file still show the warning since they are not setting a favicon, I don't remember to have had such issue before, is it possible that I have enabled some "feature" or utility on Firefox? Why it makes a drama for a missing favicon, I dont remember to have asked it to force this.

If anybody is curious about this, the module is called `faviconloader.jsm` I tried to look on Google and found no reference about how to disable this piece of...